# In PowerShell 2.0, how do you prompt the user again if this error occurs?

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script that prompts the user to input the price of a book.
So far I have this:

```
[Decimal]$BookPrice = Read-Host "Enter the price of the book"
$BookPriceRounded = "{0:C2}" -f $BookPrice
```

It works if you put in a number, but the problem is that if you put in a letter, it will display

> "Cannot convert value "5t" to type "System.Decimal". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
>   At line:1 char:20
>   + [Decimal]$BookPrice <<<<  = Read-Host "Enter the price of the book"
>       + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException"

And it will stop working.
What I want to do is instead of giving the user this error, prompt them to input numbers only. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex to replace any non-number characters:

```
[Decimal]$BookPrice = Read-Host "Enter the price of the book"
$BookPriceRounded = "{0:C2}" -f ($BookPrice -replace '[^0-9\.]','')
```

Alternatively you would have to check the input with logic:

```
Clear-Host 
$BookPrice = Read-Host "Enter the price of the book"

while ($BookPrice -NotMatch "[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?") {
    $BookPrice = Read-Host "Please enter a number or decimal only"
}

$BookPriceRounded = "{0:C2}" -f [Decimal]$BookPrice
Write-Host $Bookpricerounded
```

By the way, I added a `.` into the character class, in case you wanted to match floating point numbers. Otherwise you should change that character class to `[^0-9]` instead.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I editted my script a bit and it actually works perfectly as I wanted it to but one problem is it asks me twice when I put in a number. For example, if I put in 58, it will say "Please enter digits only" and then I'd have to put in 58 again for it to work. But if I put in letters, it will keep giving me an error (which is what I wanted) Is there anyway I can prevent it from asking me to enter the number twice?

Comment: Okay, I changed the regex a little bit. It will now match decimals and numbers more specifically. I also made the while loop condition `notmatch`. Try that one.

Comment: Hey, now when I type in a letter it just gives me the error and does not prompt me to input numbers anymore.

Comment: That would be coming up because the first and second `Read-Host` are trying to initialize the value as a decimal. I changed the code so that the only `[decimal]` initialization is when it is used in the second last line.